# How can i disable all links when one link is active in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three links that have hidden content on the side. When i click on one link the hidden content pushes the current page to the side to reveal the coinciding content. The problem with the current code is that one i click and reveal a similar content the links are still active and if i click on it, it keep moving to the left and eventually disappears. What i need to be able to do is that disable all the links when the hidden content is revealed and enable again when the content is hidden again. I am still a newbie in learning the Javascript and Jquery coding. I would appreciate the help

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#cd-team').find('a.team-mem').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //variable stores which member data needs to be clicked
    var selected_member = $(this).data('type');

    $('.cd-member-bio.'+selected_member+'').animate({
        left:'0px'
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
        'marginLeft': '+=300px'
    }, 200);

   // $( "a.team-mem" ).unbind('click');

     $('.icon-close').click(function() {
          $('.cd-member-bio').animate({
            left: "-300px"
          }, 200);
          $('body').animate({
          'marginLeft': '0'
        }, 200);
      });

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/p3g16Lwq/

P.S: if anyone can suggest a better solution to the above code i would be grateful... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this in two ways.

Close any open panels before opening the clicked one. You just need `$('.icon-close').click()` placed at the top. **OR**

Define a variable that can keep track of whether a panel is open or not. See demo below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var open = false;
    $('#cd-team').find('a.team-mem').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if( !open ) {
            open = true;
            //variable stores which member data needs to be clicked
            var selected_member = $(this).data('type');

            $('.cd-member-bio.'+selected_member+'').animate({
                left:'0px'
            }, 200);

            $('body').animate({
                'marginLeft': '+=300px'
            }, 200);

            // $( "a.team-mem" ).unbind('click');

            $('.icon-close').click(function() {
                open = false;
                $('.cd-member-bio').animate({
                    left: "-300px"
                }, 200);
                $('body').animate({
                    'marginLeft': '0'
                }, 200);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/p3g16Lwq/10/)

Answer (score 1):

just changed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3g16Lwq/1/

added a bool to check, if the member box is already shown.

```
var shownMember = false;
```

the left-margin animation only starts, when this is not the case (and changes the bool to true):

```
if (!shownMember) {
        $('body').animate({
            'marginLeft': '+=300px'
        }, 200, function () {
            shownMember = true;
        });
    }
```

on close, it's reset to false:

```
$('.icon-close').click(function () {
        $('.cd-member-bio').animate({
            left: "-300px"
        }, 200);
        $('body').animate({
            'marginLeft': '0'
        }, 200);
        shownMember = false;
    });
```

there are better solutions for the problem, but it will do...

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response... Can you tell me what this condition does especially the exclamation before the variable  -  !shownMember

Comment: ! is the .not. operator (in a lot of programming languages) if(shownMember) would only work, if the var == true if(!shownMember) is the same as if(shownmember == false)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a class for revealing the hidden content and use CSS `transition` property to give animation.

Also, you do not need to bind click function handler to 'icon-close' every time link is clicked. So, it can be moved outside.

Last thing is instead of giving `margin-left:0px` to body you can use `-=300px` because different browsers may take initial margin for body that is not 0.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3g16Lwq/11/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#cd-team').find('a.team-mem').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // If any of 'cd-memeber-bio' element is revealed, just return from function
    if ($('.cd-member-bio.revealed').length)
      return;

    //variable stores which member data needs to be clicked
    var selected_member = $(this).data('type');

    $('.cd-member-bio.' + selected_member + '').addClass('revealed');

    $('body').animate({
      'marginLeft': '+=300px'
    }, 200);

  });

  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.cd-member-bio').removeClass('revealed');
    $('body').animate({
      'marginLeft': '-=300px'
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  /* prevent ie from showing the horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.cd-member-bio {
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #009999;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.2s;
  transition: left 0.2s;
}
.revealed {
  left: 0px;
}
table {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  width: 90%;
}
table th {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
table td {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  padding: 5px;
}
.team-mem {
  color: #009999;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.team-mem img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .portfolio-item {
    height: 340px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio-item {
    height: 380px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .portfolio-item {
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Content -->
<section id="cd-team" class="cd-section container">

  <!-- Page Heading -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="page-header text-left"><small style="color:#000; font-weight:bold;">Test content</small>
                </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

  <!-- Projects Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item" data-filter="one">
      <a href="#0" class="team-mem" data-type="member-1">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
        <p class="mem-name">Member 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item" data-filter="one">
      <a href="#0" class="team-mem" data-type="member-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
        <p class="mem-name">Member 2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item" data-filter="two">
      <a href="#0" class="team-mem" data-type="member-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
        <p class="mem-name">Member 3</p>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</section>
<div class="cd-member-bio member-1">
  <div class="icon-close" `style="z-index:100000;">
    close
  </div>
  <div class="cd-bio-content">
    <h1>Member 1 </h1>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-bio-content -->
</div>
<!-- cd-member-bio -->

<div class="cd-member-bio member-2">
  <div class="icon-close" `style="z-index:100000;">
    close
  </div>
  <div class="cd-bio-content">
    <h1>Member 2</h1>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-bio-content -->
</div>
<!-- cd-member-bio -->

<div class="cd-member-bio member-3">
  <div class="icon-close" `style="z-index:100000;">
    close
  </div>
  <div class="cd-bio-content">
    <h1>Member 3</h1>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-bio-content -->
</div>
<!-- cd-member-bio -->
```